# Regarding tables

Tags: lua, lua-table, love2d

I was writing my code for a game I was making and I ran into an error in the function

```
function ent:Smoke()
  table.insert( self.smokes, (time = 3, x = self.x, y = self.y) )
end
```

It tells me that ')' is expected near '=', is it because of the double parentheses? If so/not, how can I fix this? Thank you

Comment: `{time = 3, x = self.x, y = self.y}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for Lua table is to enclose the items inside curly brackets. You are instead using parenthesis. Change the call to:

```
table.insert( self.smokes, {time = 3, x = self.x, y = self.y} )
```